# @@JsonProperty annotation is not working for java property

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a controller which accepts a input request as json

```
{
           "default": true
}
```

Default is a java keyword so I made it as

```
@JsonProperty(“default”)
Private boolean isDefault;
```

I have a client which I need to make a call which accepts only `default` which is boolean.

When I do the above way of sending request its not sending as `default: true` it sends as `isDefault:true` and the call to the client is failing for me. Saying `isDefault` is not there.

Can someone please help?

On the same note I get a response from client with default again with the same value I sent. How do I accept the response in my system? I tried with JsonProperty it didn’t work though. And also @SerializedName from gson. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: show your code its not enough with @JsonProperty it should have worked

Comment: I gave the pojo where I am adding the jsonproperty and request I am sending...LMK what else you want I can provide

Comment: show your maven dependencies your controller and pojo class. send the complete code I literally tested its working for me. Here is the returned result in my case. {"default":true}. If you like i will paste my solution down there.Its pretty basic

Comment: Your code will work. More likely you are not actually running this code.

Comment: It didn't work with the dependency I had...I tested with new dependency and it worked by changing my gradle dependency from "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1"

Answer (score 1):

I have created the sample project. Here is what I have got.

Pojo class:

```
    public class Pojo {
    @JsonProperty("default")
    private boolean isDefault;

    public boolean isDefault() {
        return isDefault;
    }

    public void setDefault(boolean aDefault) {
        isDefault = aDefault;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/default")
    public Pojo test(){
        Pojo p = new Pojo();
        p.setDefault(true);
        return p;
    }
}
```

pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

output:

```
{"default":true}
```

Comment: I tested it worked by changing my gradle dependency from 
 "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to 
   "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1"